How to search azure devops pipeline Array and return index
I would like to search an array and get the index of the found element.  Is there a way to do this without using bash/powershell scripts?
Here's the sample code to search the array.
Parameters
- name: list
    type: object
    default:
      - A
      - B
      - C
      - D

stages:
- ${{ each item in parameters.list }}:
  - ${{ if eq( item, 'B ) }}:
    - script: echo ${{ item }}


Hi orange-lily, can you share that why you don't want to use bash/PowerShell scripts?

It’s more to what is possible in the ymal, without resorting to creating bespoke code

Hi orange-lily, thanks for your response. It appears that the feature you need does not exist currently. Maybe you can request the feature for Azure DevOps here to help the feature better.

What are you trying to achieve, i.e. what is your scenario?

According to https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/access-iterator-inside-each-loop/1192557 accessing the index is not possible.

Azure DevOps YAML supports limited Expressions and I have not found a way to find the index of an element in an array without using scripts. Using scripts to get information is normal and fast in the pipeline.
Here are some bash/PowerShell scripts tasks to get the index for your reference.
parameters:
  - name: list
    type: object
    default:
      - A
      - B
      - C
      - D

stages:
  - stage: A
    jobs:
      - job: FindIndex
        steps:
          - ${{ each item in parameters.list }}:
            - ${{ if eq(item, 'B') }}:
              - powershell: |
                  $json = '${{ convertToJson(parameters.list) }}'
                  $array = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json
                  $index = 0
                  foreach ($item in $array) {
                    if ($item -eq 'B') {
                      Write-Output "Found B at index $index"
                      break
                    }
                    $index++
                  }
                displayName: 'Find index of ${{ item }}'
              - script: |
                  index=0
                  for item in $(echo "${MY_JSON}" | jq -r '.[]'); do
                    if [ "$item" == "B" ]; then
                      echo "Found B at index $index"
                      break
                    fi
                    index=$((index + 1))
                  done
                env:
                  MY_JSON: ${{ convertToJson(parameters.list) }}
                displayName: 'Find index of ${{ item }}'
      - job: FindEachIndex
        steps:
          - ${{ each item in parameters.list }}:
            - powershell: |
                $json = '${{ convertToJson(parameters.list) }}'
                $array = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json
                $index = 0
                foreach ($currentItem in $array) {
                  if ($currentItem -eq '${{ item }}') {
                    Write-Output "Current Item: $currentItem, Index: $index"
                  }
                  $index++
                }
              displayName: 'Find index of ${{ item }}'


